# Angular $q.reject().success(), does that make sense?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I'm reading a book called *MEAN Machine*, and as I'm getting to the late chapters, I've got stuck at one of the sample applications, that doesn't seem to work.

The problem seems to occur because my *mainController* calls *authService*'s `Auth.getUser()` method, which may return either a `$http.get()` or a `$q.reject()`. As I'm not logged in, it returns `$q.reject()`, and fails to chain the `.success()` promise.

It throws following exception:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function at mainCtrl.js:13

My code is as follows.

---

**CONTROLLER**
*`mainController`*

```
angular.module('mainCtrl', [])
    .controller('mainController', function($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
        var vm = this;

        // check to see if a user is logged in on every request
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function () {
            vm.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();

            // get user information on route change
            Auth.getUser()

                /* ========= PROBLEM HERE ========= */
                .success(function (data) {
                    vm.user = data;
                });
        });

        // ... other stuff
    });
```

---

**SERVICE**
*`authService`*

```
angular.module('authService', [])

    // ===================================================
    // auth factory to login and get information
    // inject $http for communicating with the API
    // inject $q to return promise objects
    // inject AuthToken to manage tokens
    // ===================================================
    .factory('Auth', function ($http, $q, AuthToken) {

        var authFactory = {};

        // get the user info

        /* ========= PROBLEM LEADS HERE ========= */

        authFactory.getUser = function () {
            if (AuthToken.getToken())
                return $http.get('/api/me', { cache: true });
            else {
                return $q.reject({ message: 'User has no token.' });
            }
        }
```

---

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you defined an `.isLoggedIn()` method in `Auth`?

Comment: Hi @JLRishe. Yes, it's already defined. The problem really occurs when it tries to call .success() on return from $q.reject(). But thanks for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace your call to the service with:

**Solution A: `.then(successCallback, errorCallback)`:**

```
Auth.getUser().then(
    function (response) { ... },                // success handler
    function (response) {                       // error handler
        // case where user is not logged in
        // or http request fails
});
```

or

**Solution B: `.then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback)`:**

```
Auth.getUser()
    .then(function (response) { ... })         // success handler
    .catch(function (response) {               // error handler
        // case where user is not logged in
        // or http request fails
    });
```

---

### Explanation :

Your `getUser` method is defined as follows :

```
authFactory.getUser = function () {
    if (AuthToken.getToken())
        return $http.get('/api/me', { cache: true });
    else {
        return $q.reject({ message: 'User has no token.' });
    }
}
```

But the `success` and the `error` shorthand methods are specific to `$http`. They doesn't exist in angular's promise `$q` API. Therefore, when the user is **not** logged in, because you are returning a `$q` promise, you got an `undefined is not a function`.

The methods you can call on a `$q` promise object are ([link to documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)) :

- `then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)`
- `catch(errorCallback)` which is a shorthand for `promise.then(null, errorCallback)`
- `finally(callback, notifyCallback)`

Comment: Thank you very much, for both solution and explanation! It solved the problem.